# List all values used in a session from a variable in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I did a simple search view to query based on this inputs.

```
def search(request):
    try:
        query_x = request.GET.get('query_x')
        query_y = request.GET.get('query_y')
        points_returned = request.GET.get('points_returned')
        distance_condition = request.GET.get('distance_condition')

        object_list = Points.objects.filter(
            geom_point__distance_lte=('POINT({0} {1})'.format(query_x, query_y), D(km=10))
            ).order_by('geom_point')[:int(points_returned)]

        request.session['query_x'] = query_x

        return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'object_list': object_list})
    except KeyError:
        return render_to_response('home.html')
```

This search will be used many times (probably with same values) so I want to save and list all the inputs used to do the query by the user (for query_x and query_y variables). I already achieved to get the value in template, but just the last one input appear when I put `{{request.session.query_x}}` in the template to see the results - I need to get all values used.

Comment: The problem was solved using `request.session['query_x'].append(query_x)`instead of `request.session['query_x'] = query_x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From wherever you are calling search function you can create a session variable of list there before calling search
`request.session['query_x'] = list()`.
instead of doing `request.session['query_x'] = query_x` you can simply do `request.session['query_x'].append(query_x)` and access all **query_x** using `request.session['query_x']`

Comment: Hi Ashish, thanks for you reply. I updated my code using your suggestions but still get just one result (the last search input that I used in query_x). I put the `request.session['query_x'] = list()` and `request.session['query_x'].append(query_x)`after the query in my original code.

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. Works well now! I used just `request.session['query_x'].append(query_x)` and know I see all the requests made. Thanks!

Comment: If I put only the